# Method not being called from mainactivity on button click

Tags: java, android, methods

I have created two activities. Activity Main has button and on click on this button i m calling method of another class which is extended to AppCompActivity. The method name is mailconfig as shown below. Confidential Information has deleted from parameters.

```
public class ButtonActionFrontPage extends AppCompatActivity{


  protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
    }

    public void mailconfig(String message) throws EmailException {

        String username = "";
        String password = "";
        String from = "";
        String replyto = "";

        String mailto = "";
        String subject = "";

        Email email = new SimpleEmail();
        email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
        email.isStartTLSEnabled();
        email.setHostName("");
        email.setSmtpPort(26);
        email.setSubject(subject);
        email.addReplyTo(replyto);
        email.setFrom(from);
        email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator(username, password));
        email.setMsg(message);
        email.addTo(mailto);
        email.send();

       Toast.makeText(ButtonActionFrontPage.this,"Thanks for submitting ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        System.out.println("Sent");

    }
}
```

I a using below code to call above method.

```
feedbackbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    ButtonActionFrontPage buttonActionFrontPage = new ButtonActionFrontPage();
                  String  message = quickfbet.getText().toString();
                    buttonActionFrontPage.mailconfig(message);
                } catch (EmailException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        });
```

What wrong in this code, why not executing.

Comment: Try to do the same things just delete extends AppCompatActivity and onCreate method in your ButtonActionFrontPage

Comment: Instead of creating it in activity class, create your email method in a simple java class and then call it from there

Comment: 1. If i delete extends and oncreate, i have to delete Toast Also, as start showing error. Moreover, even after deleting, it is not working in this case. Surprising is when i create a simple method with sop statement, call it, it worked.

Comment: Vivek, actually i will be requiring this method at many places to send mail, so by doing this, i need not to copy whole method in every activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java classes are different with respect to `Android` `Activity`. As Android Activity has something called [life cycle](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html).

If some functionality has to be implemented, you don't even create an Activity. Just a plain Java class is enough.

Activity can be used when there is an user interaction (infact which is not always true, but purely depends on the business logic). Inorder to initiate an Activity, [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) is used. Which will initiate the activity with memory allocation and other related features.

For your case, the initiation of button should be done in `onCreate` of ButtonActionFrontPage and through click listener as shown below

```
Button feedbackbtn;
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        feedbackbtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_ID);
        feedbackbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 new PlainJavaClass().mailconfig("msg",ButtonActionFrontPage.class);
                }
        });
    }
```

For the business logic just use PlainJavaClass with method and `context` if you have to show any `Toast`/`Dialog`/`ProgressBar`

```
class PlainJavaClass{

      public void mailconfig(String message, Context context)  {

        Log.v("TAG","mailconfig with message="+message);
        //Your logic
        Toast.makeText(context,"Thanks for submitting ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: made changes but still no benefit. Not getting toast, email and SOP.

Comment: Have you debugged ? Put some Log.v and check, if the steps for sending message are completed or not

Comment: I have updated the code. Check if your control comes to it or not.

Comment: V/TAG: mailconfig with message=hi
W/System.err: org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : mail.xxxxxx.com:465

Comment: W/art: Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/WfdCommon.jar': I/O Error

       [ 09-30 16:48:34.731 18330:18330 W/         ]
       Unable to open '/system/framework/WfdCommon.jar': No such file or directory

Comment: Answer to this topic is resolved "Method not being called from mainactivity on button click"  . As you are getting call till your method. Log.v("TAG","mailconfig with message="+message);       .. You should probably ask another question, as email sending is failing .. "Sending the email to the following server failed"

Answer (score 0):

Class would be like this

```
public class ButtonActionFrontPage {


    public void mailconfig(Context context,String message) throws EmailException {

        String username = "";
        String password = "";
        String from = "";
        String replyto = "";

        String mailto = "";
        String subject = "";

        Email email = new SimpleEmail();
        email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
        email.isStartTLSEnabled();
        email.setHostName("");
        email.setSmtpPort(26);
        email.setSubject(subject);
        email.addReplyTo(replyto);
        email.setFrom(from);
        email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator(username, password));
        email.setMsg(message);
        email.addTo(mailto);
        email.send();

       Toast.makeText(context,"Thanks for submitting ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        System.out.println("Sent");

    }
}
```

And Calling function like this

```
feedbackbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    ButtonActionFrontPage buttonActionFrontPage = new ButtonActionFrontPage();
                  String  message = quickfbet.getText().toString();
                    buttonActionFrontPage.mailconfig(getApplicationContext(),message);
                } catch (EmailException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        });
```

Comment: Without extends, code is giving error on Toast.  Error:(43, 10) error: no suitable method found for makeText(ButtonActionFrontPage,String,int)
method Toast.makeText(Context,CharSequence,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; ButtonActionFrontPage cannot be converted to Context)
method Toast.makeText(Context,int,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; ButtonActionFrontPage cannot be converted to Context)

Comment: This is another error if i change calling function. Error:(51, 42) error: method mailconfig in class ButtonActionFrontPage cannot be applied to given types;
required: String
found: Context,String
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: can you please post your toast line here

Comment: Toast.makeText(ButtonActionFrontPage.this,"Thanks for submitting",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: if you use code that i have added then there will be  Toast.makeText(context,"Thanks for submitting ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); it will not give you error

Comment: [ 09-30 16:52:31.035 20147:20147 W/         ]
       Unable to open '/system/framework/WfdCommon.jar': No such file or directory
W/art: Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/WfdCommon.jar': I/O Error
W/System.err: org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : mail.xxxx.com:465

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ButtonActionFrontPage extends AppCompatActivity{

static ButtonActionFrontPage instance;


  protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        instance = this;
    }

  public static ButtonActionFrontPage getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        instance = null;
    }
}
```

and calling the function:

```
feedbackbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    ButtonActionFrontPage buttonActionFrontPage =  ButtonActionFrontPage.getInstance();                     String  message = quickfbet.getText().toString();
                    buttonActionFrontPage.mailconfig(message);
                } catch (EmailException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```